# nginx reverse proxy params docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, parameters, nginx-reverse-proxy

when doing a post to  let `url = '/api/registerCoin'` it works. 
`nginx` forwards this to `server:3000`, which is good!
When I try the `post` to `/api/updatePost` with params
nginx doesn't seem to point to the server.

I am getting:

```
/api/findPostData Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in the browser.
```

Is that due to the params being added to the url? 
I am having the same issue making a post to:

```
 POST https://v2.steemconnect.com/api/broadcast 500 ()
```

this seems not to route via server.

even though: `https://v2.steemconnect.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=cr`
for oauth authentication does work from the same component.
This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong with the `nginx conf`.

```html
var dilta = this.quill.getContents();
let url = '/api/updatePost';
const params = new HttpParams().set('permlink', permlink);
return this.http.post(url ,dilta,{ params })
```

```
 worker_processes 2 ;

 events {
    worker_connections 1024;
 }
 http {
   upstream my-server {
 server myserver:3000;
  }

upstream client {
server client:4200;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
    location  ^~ /api/* {
        proxy_pass http://my-server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}        
}

 }
```