# wget works but can't request from React app

Tags: reactjs, http, docker, nginx, wget

I have two linked Docker containers `api` and `frontend`. `frontend` is a ReactJS app inside `nginx` container. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

and the run command:

```
docker run --name frontend --link api:api -p 80:80 frontend_img
```

When I `sh` inside `frontend` and run:

`$ wget http://api:8080/api/users`

works fine and I'm able to fetch the users. However, when my app tries to fetch the data, I'm getting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error in the Chrome console.

This is my JS code:

```
fetchUsers() {
    return axios.get('http://api:8080/api/users')
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
}
```

What am I missing? Do I need to configure something in NGINX in order to be able to fetch the data from the `api` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to this accepted answer [docker nginx ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160019/docker-nginx-err-name-not-resolved)

> When connecting to containers with a reverse proxy, all the URL's used
>   by the application need to point to that reverse proxy and not the
>   application. Typically you do this by giving a path in the URL without
>   a hostname.

First, I created a `default.conf` nginx file to add a `location` statement to redirect calls to my api container:

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://api:8080;
}
```

Then, in my webapp, I change my JS code so I request against `/api/users`, without hostname:

```
fetchUsers() {
    return axios.get('/api/users')
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
}
```

Finally, in the Dockerfile, I replace default `default.conf` nginx file with the edited one:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

That's all!